# Javascript: window.location reloads the same page in which script is written

Tags: javascript, html

I have a login form on a page (Home.html) which takes email ID and password. It is validated using javascript and redirects to another page (Login.html)

```
function redirect() {
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  if(email=='user@gmail.com' && password=='user')
     window.location = 'Login.html';
  else
     alert("Wrong credentials");
}


<form onsubmit='redirect()' method='post'>
```

If wrong credentials are entered then the alert box is displayed as expected but when the correct credentials are entered then Home.html is reloaded instead on going to Login.html

I have tried changing window.location to window.location.href but that doesn't help.

It works properly if form tag is not used and onclick is used in button tag to call the redirect() function.

Comment: The problem is that your code does nothing to prevent the normal native browser action associated with submitting the `<form>`.

Comment: Authentication in client side is pointless. Anybody can inspect the source code and find the password.

Comment: @Oriol I understand server side code should be used and this page is not secure at all, but this is just a local website for college project. It won't go on the internet. Thanks for your inputs, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting a form will cause a new page to load. That will cancel any `location` assignment performed by JS from its submit event.

Since you have no action attribute, the new page that is loaded is the one with the same URL as the existing page.

You need to cancel the default behaviour of the submit event (i.e. the form submission). The quick and dirty way to do that is to return false from the submit event handler function:

```
<form onsubmit='redirect(); return false;' method='post'>
```

---

Modern code would bind the event handler with JavaScript instead of using intrinsic event handlers in the first place:

```
<form method='post'>
```

and

```
function redirect(event) {
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  if(email=='user@gmail.com' && password=='user')
     window.location = 'Login.html';
  else
     alert("Wrong credentials");
  event.preventDefault();
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", redirect);
```

---

Robust code would be written [unobtrusively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) so that if the [JavaScript failed](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) (which [it will](https://gds.blog.gov.uk/2013/10/21/how-many-people-are-missing-out-on-javascript-enhancement/)), then the form would submit as normal, and server side code would perform the activity instead.

---

And all that aside, the username, password, and unsecured URL that the user gets redirected to are all visible in the page's source code, so you really need to be doing this on the server and only on the server anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot Quentin for this explanation. And also your answer did work for me.

Comment: I understand server side code should be used and this page is not secure at all, but this is just a local website for college project.

Answer (score 0):

`<form onsubmit='redirect();return false;' method='post'>`

Answer (score 0):

Form will not be submitted if you `return false` from redirect method , try `return false` when error occurs.

```
function redirect() {
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  if(email=='user@gmail.com' && password=='user')
     window.location = 'Login.html';
  else
   {
     alert("Wrong credentials");
    return false;
  }
}
```

And change form to

```
<form onsubmit='return redirect()' method='post'>
```

Comment: Returning false from the `require` function won't have any effect.

Comment: use this answer and add to your form element the return before the function: `<form onsubmit='return redirect();' method='post'>`